# Order Authors in wp by custom field

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

Working on Wordpress. I need to add a new field like Expert and their Order (or may be weight field) for author, this is quite easy to do.

I need to make a query for authors, where all authors will get listed... preferably using this  http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/wp_list_authors

However, I need to order authors by the Order field (or weight field)..

Any idea, on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

In your query, use these arguments :

```
 'meta_key' => 'Order',
 'orderby'   => 'meta_value'
```

The query should be ordered by your field's value. You can also change orderby from ASC to DESC, like this :

```
'order' => 'ASC'
```

Actually, check if `meta_key` will work. But I do know that `orderby` and `order` have been added in WordPress 3.1 to the `wp_list_author` function. If it does not work, then do the same (use the indicated arguments) but with a custom `wp_query`.